# Class not recognized

Tags: java

I've just installed the Java SDK 8, set the PATH and the CLASSPATH variables, put javax.mail.jar file in the bin directory, but when I try to compile my problem, all javax.mail classes aren't recongnized:

```
C:\Java>javac SendMail.java
SendMail.java:5: error: package javax.mail does not exist
import javax.mail.Message;
```

Here is the content of my CLASSPATH variable:

```
C:\Java>echo %CLASSPATH%
C:\"Program Files"\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\lib;.
```

And here is the content of the bin directory:

```
C:\Java>dir C:\"Program Files"\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\lib\*.jar
ant-javafx.jar
dt.jar
javafx-mx.jar
javax.mail.jar
jconsole.jar
sa-jdi.jar
tools.jar
```

What's the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Classpath should contain the individual JAR files, not the directory that contains the jar files. Also the `lib` directory contains stuff you normally don't need. So you want just:

```
set CLASSPATH="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\lib\javax.mail.jar"
```

Also you can add classpath on your `java.exe` command line:

```
java.exe -cp "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\lib\javax.mail.jar" SendMail
```

Comment: It should be possible to define it as `PATH/*` - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html (*wildcard*).

Comment: Thanks @PavelHoral - so yes it appears wildcards are possible. You learn every day. Likely only for java 6 and newer.

Comment: I removed the quotation marks and pointed to the javax.mail.jar file and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

(I haven't checked that myself, but...)

`c:\"Program Files"\something` doesn't seem like a good path to me.

Try setting CLASSPATH to:

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\lib";.
```

Comment: Windows doesn't recognize spaces as valid characters in paths, so you have to use quotation marks in a command prompt. But maybe this rule doesn't apply to paths defined in environment variables.